# FullPage.js auto up scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullpage.js

I am using fullPage.js on my project, i don't know why but when i reach the bottom of a section, fullPage.js automatically scroll me up again to the top of my web.
Is there any web to turn this function of?
thanks.

Update : last thing i noticed is that fullPage.js trying to scroll me to nearest section, because when i add empty section to my existing one and scroll near it, fullpage.js would automatically scroll me to the one on the bottom

this is my html code, for the section

```
<div class="container" id="fullpage">
                <div class="section">
                    <div class="announce slide" id="announce">
                        <h1 class="tz-title-4 tzcolor-blue">
                            <span class="tzweight_Bold">Announcements</span>
                        </h1>
                        <div class="section_group" id="newsContainer">
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                        <div class="holderNews text-center">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="menu slide" id="menu">
                        <h2 class="tz-title-2">
                            <span class="tzweight_Bold">Menus</span>
                        </h2>
                        <div class="grid_1">
                            <div class="box_1">
                                <div class="col-md-3 menu_left">
                                    <div class="menu_vertical">
                                        <section class="accordation_menu">
                                            <div>
                                                <input id="label-1" name="lida" type="radio" checked/>
                                                <label for="label-1" id="item1"><i class="ferme"> </i>Breakfast<i class="icon-plus-sign i-right1"></i><i class="icon-minus-sign i-right2"></i></label>
                                                <div class="content" id="a1">
                                                    <div class="scrollbar" id="style-2">
                                                        <div class="force-overflow">
                                                            <ul class="news_list">
                                                                <li class="date">
                                                                    <img src="assets/images/s1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                                                                </li>
                                                                <li class="date_desc">
                                                                    <h5>1. Menu</h5>
                                                                    <p>Bacon and eggs , pancakes , Olive Oil ..</p>
                                                                </li>
                                                                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                                                            </ul>
                                                            <ul class="news_list">
                                                                <li class="date">
                                                                    <img src="assets/images/s2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                                                                </li>
                                                                <li class="date_desc">
                                                                    <h5>2. Menu</h5>
                                                                    <p>Bacon and eggs , pancakes , Olive Oil ..</p>
                                                                </li>
                                                                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                                                            </ul>
                                                            <ul class="news_list">
                                                                <li class="date">
                                                                    <img src="assets/images/s3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                                                                </li>
                                                                <li class="date_desc">
                                                                    <h5>3. Menu</h5>
                                                                    <p>Bacon and eggs , pancakes , Olive Oil ..</p>
                                                                </li>
                                                                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                                                            </ul>
                                                            <ul class="news_list">
                                                                <li class="date">
                                                                    <img src="assets/images/s4.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                                                                </li>
                                                                <li class="date_desc">
                                                                    <h5>4. Menu</h5>
                                                                    <p>Bacon and eggs , pancakes , Olive Oil ..</p>
                                                                </li>
                                                                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                                                            </ul>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div>
                                                <input id="label-2" name="lida" type="radio"/>
                                                <label for="label-2" id="item2"><i class="icon-leaf" id="i2"></i>Launch<i class="icon-plus-sign i-right1"></i><i class="icon-minus-sign i-right2"></i></label>
                                                <div class="content" id="a2">
                                                    <div class="scrollbar" id="style-2">
                                                        <div class="force-overflow">
                                                            <ul class="news_list">
                                                                <li class="date">
                                                                    <img src="assets/images/s1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                                                                </li>
                                                                <li class="date_desc">
                                                                    <h5>1. Menu</h5>
                                                                    <p>Bacon and eggs , pancakes , Olive Oil ..</p>
                                                                </li>
                                                                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                                                            </ul>
                                                            <ul class="news_list">
                                                                <li class="date">
                                                                    <img src="assets/images/s2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                                                                </li>
                                                                <li class="date_desc">
                                                                    <h5>2. Menu</h5>
                                                                    <p>Bacon and eggs , pancakes , Olive Oil ..</p>
                                                                </li>
                                                                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                                                            </ul>
                                                            <ul class="news_list">
                                                                <li class="date">
                                                                    <img src="assets/images/s3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                                                                </li>
                                                                <li class="date_desc">
                                                                    <h5>3. Menu</h5>
                                                                    <p>Bacon and eggs , pancakes , Olive Oil ..</p>
                                                                </li>
                                                                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                                                            </ul>
                                                            <ul class="news_list">
                                                                <li class="date">
                                                                    <img src="assets/images/s4.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                                                                </li>
                                                                <li class="date_desc">
                                                                    <h5>4. Menu</h5>
                                                                    <p>Bacon and eggs , pancakes , Olive Oil ..</p>
                                                                </li>
                                                                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                                                            </ul>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div>
                                                <input id="label-3" name="lida" type="radio"/>
                                                <label for="label-3" id="item3"><i class="icon-trophy" id="i3"></i>Dinner<i class="icon-plus-sign i-right1"></i><i class="icon-minus-sign i-right2"></i></label>
                                                <div class="content" id="a3">
                                                    <div class="scrollbar" id="style-2">
                                                        <div class="force-overflow">
                                                            <ul class="news_list">
                                                                <li class="date">
                                                                    <img src="assets/images/s1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                                                                </li>
                                                                <li class="date_desc">
                                                                    <h5>1. Menu</h5>
                                                                    <p>Bacon and eggs , pancakes , Olive Oil ..</p>
                                                                </li>
                                                                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                                                            </ul>
                                                            <ul class="news_list">
                                                                <li class="date">
                                                                    <img src="assets/images/s2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                                                                </li>
                                                                <li class="date_desc">
                                                                    <h5>2. Menu</h5>
                                                                    <p>Bacon and eggs , pancakes , Olive Oil ..</p>
                                                                </li>
                                                                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                                                            </ul>
                                                            <ul class="news_list">
                                                                <li class="date">
                                                                    <img src="assets/images/s3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                                                                </li>
                                                                <li class="date_desc">
                                                                    <h5>3. Menu</h5>
                                                                    <p>Bacon and eggs , pancakes , Olive Oil ..</p>
                                                                </li>
                                                                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                                                            </ul>
                                                            <ul class="news_list">
                                                                <li class="date">
                                                                    <img src="assets/images/s4.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                                                                </li>
                                                                <li class="date_desc">
                                                                    <h5>4. Menu</h5>
                                                                    <p>Bacon and eggs , pancakes , Olive Oil ..</p>
                                                                </li>
                                                                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                                                            </ul>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </section>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-9 menu_right">
                                    <h4>Breakfast</h4>
                                    <div class="grid_2" id="menuContainer">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                                <div class="holderMenu text-center">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <h2 class="tz-title-3">
                                <!-- <span class="tzweight_Bold">Special Days</span> -->
                            </h2>
                            <div class="box_2">
                                <!-- <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="row_1">
                                        <h3>Sunday</h3>
                                        <h4>19</h4>
                                        <h3>April</h3>
                                        <div class="border"> </div>
                                        <h5>Birthday Celebrations</h5>
                                    </div>
                                </div> -->
                                <!-- <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="column_right_grid calender">
                                        <div class="cal1"><div class="clndr"><div class="clndr-controls"><div class="clndr-control-button"><p class="clndr-previous-button">previous</p></div>
                                        <div class="month">March 2014</div><div class="clndr-control-button rightalign"><p class="clndr-next-button">next</p></div></div>
                                        <table class="clndr-table" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><thead><tr class="header-days">
                                            <td class="header-day">Sun</td><td class="header-day">Mon</td><td class="header-day">T</td><td class="header-day">W</td><td class="header-day">T</td>
                                            <td class="header-day">F</td><td class="header-day">S</td></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td class="day past adjacent-month last-month calendar-day-2014-02-23">
                                                <div class="day-contents">23</div></td><td class="day past adjacent-month last-month calendar-day-2014-02-24"><div class="day-contents">24</div></td>
                                                <td class="day past adjacent-month last-month calendar-day-2014-02-25"><div class="day-contents">25</div></td>
                                                <td class="day past adjacent-month last-month calendar-day-2014-02-26"><div class="day-contents">26</div></td>
                                                <td class="day past adjacent-month last-month calendar-day-2014-02-27"><div class="day-contents">27</div></td><td class="day past adjacent-month last-month calendar-day-2014-02-28"><div class="day-contents">28</div></td><td class="day past calendar-day-2014-03-01"><div class="day-contents">1</div></td></tr><tr><td class="day past calendar-day-2014-03-02"><div class="day-contents">2</div></td><td class="day past calendar-day-2014-03-03"><div class="day-contents">3</div></td><td class="day past calendar-day-2014-03-04"><div class="day-contents">4</div></td><td class="day past calendar-day-2014-03-05"><div class="day-contents">5</div></td><td class="day past calendar-day-2014-03-06"><div class="day-contents">6</div></td><td class="day past calendar-day-2014-03-07"><div class="day-contents">7</div></td><td class="day past calendar-day-2014-03-08"><div class="day-contents">8</div></td></tr><tr><td class="day past calendar-day-2014-03-09"><div class="day-contents">9</div></td><td class="day past event calendar-day-2014-03-10"><div class="day-contents">10</div></td><td class="day past event calendar-day-2014-03-11"><div class="day-contents">11</div></td><td class="day past event calendar-day-2014-03-12"><div class="day-contents">12</div></td><td class="day past event calendar-day-2014-03-13"><div class="day-contents">13</div></td><td class="day past event calendar-day-2014-03-14"><div class="day-contents">14</div></td><td class="day past calendar-day-2014-03-15"><div class="day-contents">15</div></td></tr><tr><td class="day past calendar-day-2014-03-16"><div class="day-contents">16</div></td><td class="day past calendar-day-2014-03-17"><div class="day-contents">17</div></td><td class="day past calendar-day-2014-03-18"><div class="day-contents">18</div></td><td class="day past calendar-day-2014-03-19"><div class="day-contents">19</div></td><td class="day past calendar-day-2014-03-20"><div class="day-contents">20</div></td><td class="day past event calendar-day-2014-03-21"><div class="day-contents">21</div></td><td class="day past event calendar-day-2014-03-22"><div class="day-contents">22</div></td></tr><tr><td class="day past event calendar-day-2014-03-23"><div class="day-contents">23</div></td><td class="day past calendar-day-2014-03-24"><div class="day-contents">24</div></td><td class="day today calendar-day-2014-03-25"><div class="day-contents">25</div></td><td class="day calendar-day-2014-03-26"><div class="day-contents">26</div></td><td class="day calendar-day-2014-03-27"><div class="day-contents">27</div></td><td class="day calendar-day-2014-03-28"><div class="day-contents">28</div></td><td class="day calendar-day-2014-03-29"><div class="day-contents">29</div></td></tr><tr><td class="day calendar-day-2014-03-30"><div class="day-contents">30</div></td><td class="day calendar-day-2014-03-31"><div class="day-contents">31</div></td><td class="day adjacent-month next-month calendar-day-2014-04-01"><div class="day-contents">1</div></td><td class="day adjacent-month next-month calendar-day-2014-04-02"><div class="day-contents">2</div></td><td class="day adjacent-month next-month calendar-day-2014-04-03"><div class="day-contents">3</div></td><td class="day adjacent-month next-month calendar-day-2014-04-04"><div class="day-contents">4</div></td><td class="day adjacent-month next-month calendar-day-2014-04-05"><div class="day-contents">5</div></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div> -->
                                <!-- <div class="col-md-5 row_2">
                                    <img src="assets/images/pic9.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                                    <ul class="cake_hover">
                                        <li><a href="#"> <i class="fb"> </i>Share </a><div class="clearfix"> </div></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"> <i class="tw"> </i>Share </a><div class="clearfix"> </div></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div> -->
                                <!-- <div class="clearfix"> </div> -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="gallery slide" id="gallery">
                        <h3 class="tz-title-2">
                            <span class="tzweight_Bold">Gallery</span>
                        </h3>
                        <div class="gallery_box">
                            <div class="col_1_of_5 span_1_of_5 grid_3">
                                <img src="assets/images/g1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col_1_of_5 span_1_of_5 grid_3">
                                <img src="assets/images/g2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col_1_of_5 span_1_of_5 grid_3">
                                <img src="assets/images/g3.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col_1_of_5 span_1_of_5 grid_3 last">
                                <img src="assets/images/g4.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col_1_of_5 span_1_of_5 grid_3">
                                <img src="assets/images/g5.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt=""/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="about slide" id="about">
                        <h3 class="tz-title-2">
                            <span class="tzweight_Bold">About</span>
                        </h3>
                        <div class="about_desc">
                            <!-- <img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt=""/>
                            <p>This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit. Nam nec tellus a odio tincidunt auctor a ornare odio. Sed non  mauris vitae erat consequat auctor eu in elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris in erat justo. Nullam ac urna eu felis dapibus condimentum sit amet a augue. Sed non neque elit. Sed ut imperdiet nisi. Proin condimentum fermentum nunc. Etiam pharetra, erat sed fermentum feugiat, velit mauris egestas quam, ut aliquam massa nisl quis neque. Suspendisse in orci enim.</p>
                            <p class="about_para">This is Photoshop's version  of Lorem Ipsum. Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit. Nam nec tellus a odio tincidunt auctor a ornare odio. Sed non  mauris vitae erat consequat auctor eu in elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris in erat justo. Nullam ac urna eu felis dapibus condimentum sit amet a augue. Sed non neque elit. Sed ut imperdiet nisi. Proin condimentum fermentum nunc. Etiam pharetra, erat sed fermentum feugiat, velit mauris egestas quam, ut aliquam massa nisl quis neque. Suspendisse in orci enim.</p> -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="contact slide" id="contact">
                        <h3 class="tz-title-2">
                            <span class="tzweight_Bold">Contact</span>
                        </h3>
                        <div class="contact_box">
                            <!-- <div class="col-md-6 contact_form">
                                <form>
                                    <div class="column_2">
                                        <input type="text" class="text" value="Name" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Name';}">
                                        <input type="text" class="text" value="Email" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Email';}" style="margin-left:2.7%">

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="column_3">
                                        <textarea value="Message:" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Message';}">Message:</textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-submit1">
                                        <label class="btn btn-primary btn-normal btn-inline " target="_self"><input type="submit" value="Send"></label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="map">
                                    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d3150859.767904157!2d-96.62081048651531!3d39.536794757966845!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1408111832978"> </iframe>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"> </div> -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And this is my javascript initialization

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
  // direction: 'horizontal',
  css3: true,
  // scrollBar: true,
  autoScrolling: false,
  loopBottom: false,
  continuousVertical: false,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem, turns out it's the fitToSection.
I just need to turn it off by fitToSection: false during initialization

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [here](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#fullpagejs)

`loopBottom`: (default false) Defines whether scrolling down in the last section should scroll to the first one or not.

or either:

`continuousVertical`: (default false) Defines whether scrolling down in the last section or should scroll down to the first one and if scrolling up in the first section should scroll up to the last one. Not compatible with loopTop, loopBottom or any scroll bar present in the site (scrollBar:true or autoScrolling:false).

If that is `true` in your initialization of fullPage.js, you need to put it on `false`.

Comment: i set both of it to false already in my initialization, but it's scrolling to top when i reach end of the section